# LINQ query returning null when comparing elements in two lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am checking elements from two lists and trying to add to another list:

```
List<ProductPacking> prodSubstitute = new List<ProductPacking>();
tempList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
List<string> prodIDList = new List<string>();
for (int count = 0; count < prodSubstitute.Count; count++)
        {
            foreach (string key in tempList.Keys)
            {
                if (!prodSubstitute.Any(i => i.id == key))
                {
                    prodIDList.Add(prodSubstitute[count].id);
                }
            }
        }
```

Let's say my test id for prodSubstitute is 1,5,4,2,3. And the elements in tempList id are 1,2,3. When I loop thru prodSubstitute, if the prodSubstitute does not contain the id from tempList, it was supposed to add into prodIDList. However, with this LINQ query, it just keep returning me null instead of 5,4.

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
if (!prodIDList.Contains(prodSubstitute[count].id) && !(lstCategory.Where(x => x.Equals(categoryName)).Select(x => x).Count() >= 2))
                {
                    prodIDList.Add(prodSubstitute[count].id);
                    lstCategory.Add(categoryName);
                }
```

Comment: What if you change the prodSubstitute.Any to prodSubstitute.Contains?

Comment: You mean prodSubstitute.Contains(key) ? It shows me an error message about best overload method.Contains has invalid arguments

Comment: My apologies, it was off the top of my head and it is wrong. (Although you could probably do it this way using a comparer, it was not what I had in mind)

Comment: No problem but still thanks a lot :)

Comment: Any comment? It's still not solved yet

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var prodIDList = tempList.Keys.Except(prodSubstitute.Select(p => (string)p.id);
```

That should produce the differences between what's in `tempList` and what's in `prodSubstitute` and put it into a list of strings.

**NOTE:** this should replace all of the code you currently have.

Comment: So I should put this line inside the foreach? And if I wanted to perform some if else statement, I need a for loop for this list?

Comment: @Carol, nope this is all you need. You can get rid of the rest.

Comment: @Carol: one thing to note right now is that the code you have yields an ***empty list*** for `prodSubstitute`. For this, or any other algorithm, to yield what you're looking for something would obviously need to be in `prodSubstitute`.

Comment: But I have some other code for the if statement. See edited portion. As I need to limit the record to 2. So do I still need a for loop for the list?

Comment: @Carol: I'm sorry but I don't follow. And the edit doesn't really help either because there are local values that weren't once declared - there's just no context.

Comment: Also, I cannot change the data type for prodIDList to var, as I have some other code to for loop for the prodIDlist. Is there any other way to store the var as string?

Comment: @Carol: it can't be a `string` because it's a ***list of `string`*** objects. Further `var` is just shorthand for not having to declare the type. If the issue is you need it to be `List<string>` then just add `.ToList()` to the end of the statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. It still keep returning me null